Decode JSON object with PHP with "0" as item
I found the question "How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP" but it still does not answer my question how to address "AC" in the syntax that uses "->" WITHOUT simply referring to it by element #8 but with its label. "$jsonobj->inverters[0]->AC[0]->Power->v" does not work, but "$jsonobj['inverters'][0]['AC'][0]['Power']['v']" does.
"$jsonobj->inverters[0]->AC->0->Power->v" also fails (0 appears to be no valid item designation)
So, I'd like to get the value (v) of Power in the AC section of this JSON file with a PHP script.
{
    "inverters": [
        {
            "serial": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "name": "Block1",
            "order": 0,
            "data_age": 2,
            "poll_enabled": true,
            "reachable": true,
            "producing": true,
            "AC": {
                "0": {
                    "Power": {
                        "v": 666.2000122,
                        "u": "W",
                        "d": 1
                    },
                    "Voltage": {
                        "v": 240.1000061,
                        "u": "V",
                        "d": 1
                    },
                    "Current": {
                        "v": 2.769999981,
                        "u": "A",
                        "d": 2
                    },
                    "Frequency": {
                        "v": 50,
                        "u": "Hz",
                        "d": 2
                    },
                    "PowerFactor": {
                        "v": 0.949999988,
                        "u": "",
                        "d": 3
                    },
                    "ReactivePower": {
                        "v": 218.3999939,
                        "u": "var",
                        "d": 1
                    }
                }
            }, [...]

I was trying it with the following code that worked with a simpler structure but now fails:
$PowerV = round($jsonobj->inverters[0]->AC[0]->Power->v, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

then I asked Copilot and it came up the the following (working) alternative:
$PowerV = round($jsonobj['inverters'][0]['AC'][0]['Power']['v'], 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

I'd still like to understand what was wrong with the original code I tried.

You didn't show how you decode the JSON string.

right! I started with "$jsonobj = json_decode($output);" but then changed it to "$jsonobj = json_decode($output, true);" as suggested for the second syntax.

"$jsonobj['inverters'][0]['AC'][0]['Power']['v'] does [work]" — So what's your question?

As the duplicate explains, it depends on your exact json_decode call whether you'll get all arrays back or objects. Objects need to be addressed with the property access operator ->, while arrays use all [].

If you don't want to use associative arrays (not passing true to json_decode), you need $jsonobj->inverters[0]->AC->{'0'}->Power->v. The tricky part here is only the second 0 which is not the index of an array in your JSON structure but actually an object property. And since the syntax ->x doesn't work with property names starting with a number, you need the curly brace notation, passing a string '0'. (this is also explained in the linked duplicate, search for "Object property name contains a special character")

I wantend to understand both ways. Thanks! $jsonobj->inverters[0]->AC->{'0'}->Power->v is exactly what I was looking for!

Relevant reading: How can I access object properties with names like integers or invalid property names?
